# Открываю XML в браузере и выходит пустая белая страница - XML/XSL

Tags: c#, css, xml, xslt

Как я понимаю при запуске xml файла в браузере (Google Сhrome) должна формироваться html страничка. Но в итоге появляется просто белый экран. Где ошибка?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xslt1.xsl"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <izdelia>
    <material>сталь</material>
    <number>1</number>
    <length>1</length>
    <width>2</width>
    <heigth>3</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дерево</material>
    <number>2</number>
    <length>2</length>
    <width>3</width>
    <heigth>4</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>пластмасса</material>
    <number>3</number>
    <length>4</length>
    <width>5</width>
    <heigth>6</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>ольха</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>100</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуб</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуб</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуб</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дубо</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуба</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дубо</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуба</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>сталь</material>
    <number>1</number>
    <length>1</length>
    <width>2</width>
    <heigth>3</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дерево</material>
    <number>2</number>
    <length>2</length>
    <width>3</width>
    <heigth>4</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>пластмасса</material>
    <number>3</number>
    <length>4</length>
    <width>5</width>
    <heigth>6</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>ольха</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>100</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуб</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуб</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуб</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дубо</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуба</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дубо</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуба</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>сталь</material>
    <number>1</number>
    <length>1</length>
    <width>2</width>
    <heigth>3</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дерево</material>
    <number>2</number>
    <length>2</length>
    <width>3</width>
    <heigth>4</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>пластмасса</material>
    <number>3</number>
    <length>4</length>
    <width>5</width>
    <heigth>6</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>ольха</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>100</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуб</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуб</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуб</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дубо</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуба</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дубо</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуба</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>сталь</material>
    <number>1</number>
    <length>1</length>
    <width>2</width>
    <heigth>3</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дерево</material>
    <number>2</number>
    <length>2</length>
    <width>3</width>
    <heigth>4</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>пластмасса</material>
    <number>3</number>
    <length>4</length>
    <width>5</width>
    <heigth>6</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>ольха</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>100</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуб</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуб</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуб</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дубо</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуба</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дубо</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуба</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
</NewDataSet>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
      <h2>My Collection</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <td>MATERIAL</td>
            <td>NUMBERS</td>
            <td>L</td>
            <td>W</td>
            <td>H</td>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="NewDataSet/izdelia">
            <tr>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="material"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="number"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="length"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="width"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="heigth"/></td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>




NewDataSet 
{
    display: table;
    background: center; /* Цвет фона таблицы */
    color: green; /* Цвет текста */
    border-spacing: 1px; /* Расстояние между ячейками */
}

izdelia 
{
    display: table-row;
    line-height: 30px; 
    border-collapse: inherit;

}
material, number,length, width, heigth 
{
    display: table-cell;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6251757

Comment: XSLT в браузерах поддерживается плохо и дальше будет только хуже. Поэтому делайте трансформацию на сервере, а клиенту отдавайте готовый HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Для Chrome и Opera - залить на сайт, ругается на обращение к файлам (небезопасное).

Вот я на свой загрузил: [пример](http://javanow.xyz/test/index.xml).

Для IE - открывается сразу из файла.

Прошу прощения, изначально не понял вопроса.

Comment: В какую папку и вместе с чем?

Comment: Переответил, посмотри. Прошу прощения, сразу не понял)

Comment: @МаксимДробышев, вообще правилами хорошего тона - было бы комментировать мой ответ. Ваш вопрос я увидел случайно. Хром в силу "защиты хомячков" - не сможет. Unsafe attempt to load URL file:///home/dan/xslt1.xsl from frame with URL file:///home/dan/untitled.xml. 'file:' URLs are treated as unique security origins. Можно запустить простой https сервер, и грузануть оттуда.

Comment: @Crystal, я бы с радостью, но на сайте дня 3-4, и пока не набрал репутации. Да можно поднять денвер и тестить.

Comment: Денвер для теста, только потому, что человек не осилил открыть в FireFox'e то же самое? Это сильно. По-виндовому как-то.  > python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000